# What exactly happens to a suggested edit if the post is removed by the author or for Moderation reasons?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

[This link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7593/how-can-i-track-app-usage/115919#115919) will lead to an spam answer (affiliation wasn't disclosed; posted by `user117708`, now nuked!) which is deleted as of now, and only 10k and above reputation points holder would be able to see it.

Before I marked the answer as SPAM I rejected a suggested edit on it because I considered it to be polishing the SPAM. I also vaguely remember that, before checking my helpful flags to find that the flag was resolved as helpful I was the only one who reviewed that edit.

Now that I neither can find that deleted answer in my review history nor in the Suggestions history of the user who suggested that edit, I'm curious to know what exactly happened to that edit, or what usually happens to such an edit?

- Did other reviewers review it and the edit was resolved as approved/rejected?
- Did a Moderator (a human) review it?
- In case none of the reviewers or the Moderators reviewed it, did Community ♦ jump in and post a predefine message?
- Perhaps a possibility I'm missing here. What would that be?

Comment: Good question.  I saw the review and either hit Skip or closed the tab shortly before I nuked the user, so it "disappeared" while it was still pending.  I can't find the edit either now....

Comment: @MatthewRead Does such edits on deleted posts are visible to site Moderators, or is it for some other reason you can't find the said edit?  I tried searching similar stuff on other Meta sites using Google but couldn't find anything related. // Anyhow, I checked out my browser history, and I think either [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/99333) or [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/99355) is the link for the edit. Can you please verify them?

Comment: I can't see anything at those links.  It seems like the system completely removed the edit.

Comment: @MatthewRead OK, thanks for the help. I somewhere heard that system always keep the content though it may be away from the reach of users, and is always available to the Developers of [SE]. So should this question be migrated to [meta.se] or should I let go of this issue at all?

Comment: [Migrated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261263/154510) since it does seem broadly relevant, and maybe a bug since I am not sure there's a bigger reason to hide the edit just in this case.